# What does "-tnn" mean in "tcpdump -i eth0 -tnn dst port 80 -c 1000"

Tags: linux, tcpdump

What does `-tnn` mean in `tcpdump -i eth0 -tnn dst port 80 -c 1000`. I didn't find `-tnn` on the man page, and I didn't find it on the Internet. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can often combine options into one combined one to make typing easier.

In this case:

> `-nn`    Don't convert protocol and port numbers etc. to names either.
>
> `-t`      Don't print a timestamp on each dump line.

This also implies

> `-n`  Don't convert host addresses to names.  This can be used to avoid DNS lookups.

Comment: Thank you, but it's weird that `-nn` isn't shown in my linux tcpdump man page.

Comment: I see it on EL6, EL7, but not on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: tcpdump from tcpdump.org doesn't have `-nn` - either you specify `-n`, in which case none of the conversions to names happens, no matter how many `n`s you have, or you don't specify it, in which case tcpdump tries to do all of the conversions.  Perhaps the Red Hat/Fedora people hacked tcpdump to care how many times you specified `n`.